# Как в Python3 проверить наличие подстроки в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Можно ли как то проверить на существование подстроки в одном из значений списка в одно действие, не перебирая циклом весь список?

В списке набор имен процессов запущенных в Windows, нужно как то отфильтровать те процессы которые запущены из определенного каталога. Не хотелось бы делать это полным перебором.

Comment: Мне кажется, Вам придётся полностью перебирать список и выполнять проверку отдельно для каждого элемента (например, с помощью оператора `in`).

Comment: Что вы понимаете под полным перебором? Понятно же, что в худшем случае придётся просмотреть каждый элемент списка, а в лучшем только первый.

Comment: Без полного перебора - никак. Можно составить условие `if any("подстрока" in word for word in wordlist)`.

Comment: Перечитал вопрос внимательнее :) Если нужно отфильтровать определенные элементы из всех, то придётся проверить каждый элемент. Иначе никак. П будет этот перебор явным или неявным дело десятое.

Answer (score 1):

Я совсем не профи в python, но если не ошибаюсь вот это оптимальный вариант нахождения первого элемента удовлетворяющий предикату:

```
def containsStr(testStr, mList):
  return (next(filter(lambda x: testStr in x, mList), None) != None)

myList = ['111AAAA', '222sss', 'AAA222111']
assert not containsStr("1131", myList)
assert containsStr("111", myList)
assert containsStr("222", myList)
assert containsStr("22ss", myList)
```

Если я все верно понимаю стандартная функция filter работает через yeald - то есть весь список не приходиться проходить, если нашелся первый элемент

Comment: Я вообще его начал изучать месяц как, так что, мой вопрос больше теоретический чем практический. Как перебором это сделать я понимаю, просто я хочу понять в целях изучения фичь питона, можно ли и как. Спасибо проверю как это работает.

Comment: ну а я так и вовсе джавист - в онлайн редакторе накрапал:)) да я думаю что если загнать ему файлик на несолько тыщев строк, и в потоке искать предикат, то сразу станет ясно по таймингу как он обрабатывает этот поиск, лениво или не очень)

Comment: ну так и я PHP и VB.NET программист. А что за онлайн редактор?

Comment: https://repl.it/languages/python3

Answer (score 0):

Пусть есть список путей и целевой путь:

```
paths = ...
needle_path = r'C:\some\path\'
```

Выводим только те пути, которые попадают в нужный (начинаются с определенной строки):

```
print([p for p in paths if p.startswith(needle_path)])
```

Альтернативно, с помощью библиотеки [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) выводим пути соответствующие шаблону:

```
from pathlib import Path
print([p for p in paths if Path(p).match(r'C:\some\path\*')])
```